# Count row only by date without time using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Check the `CountEmailChart` carefully. Here I am taking input of `DateTime` which is fully formatted date with time. But the problem is I want to compare only the date, not time, on Entity Framework below to count number of rows. Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Controller code:

```
public int CountEmailChart(DateTime date, int campaignID)
{
    int count = dbcontext.CampaignEmails
                         .Count(x => x.DateSigned == date && x.CampaignID == campaignID);
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. `.Date` property on `DateTime` object will return only Date part.

If you are using Entity Framework 6 then.

```
date = date.Date;
int count = dbcontext.CampaignEmails.Count(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateSigned) == date.Date && x.CampaignID == campaignID);
```

Else

```
date = date.Date;
int count = dbcontext.CampaignEmails.Count(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateSigned) == date.Date && x.CampaignID == campaignID);
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/nHZCrd your answer is perfect but see i gets this error after using your code

Answer (score 1):

Karan's answer is correct but resulting query won't use an index for DateSigned. If a such index exist (or combined index for CampaignID and DateSigned columns) you may prefer this approach:

```
var startDate = date.Date;
var endDate = date.Date.AddDay(1);
int count = dbcontext.CampaignEmails.Count(x => x.CampaignID == campaignID && x.DateSigned >= startDate && x.DateSigned < endDate);
```